# Scrollable DockWidgetArea in QMainWindow

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

Is there any possibility to make DockWidgetArea in QMainWindow scrollable? I have many instances of QDockWidget that cannot fit into the area without scrolling. Basically, I need to have two “side bars”, one on the left, second on the right of the main window. These side bars has to be floatable on the whole and so be able to be moved to secondary monitor.

I have tried adding three instances of QMainWindow into the horizontal layout, used the middle one for showing the main application content and the rest as a dock areas – their central widget has zero size.

It works except that I am not able to add a scrollbar into these "dock areas". More precisely, I can add a QScrollBar as a central widget of these QMainWindows, but it breaks docking ability and that is all.

In Qt 4 there was QDockArea widget, but in Qt 5 one has only a minimal control of the dock areas behavior.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: According to [this other forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/102559/adding-scroll-bar-to-dock-widget-area), no, it is not possible.